# I am using Spring boot JPA, I have an issue when I want to delete an entity from db

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have 3 entities ( House, Floors and Rooms)
I have the OneToMany relations in place, I am able to add Floors into the house(floors and rooms) but
I am not able to delete them using FloorRepository and it throws me an error like the relations between House and floor (house_floors) still exists. And I don't know how to delete also this intermediate table. also if I try to put this query:

```
@Query("DELETE FROM house_floors hf WHERE hf.floor IN :floors")
void deleteHouseFloorsAndRoomsByFloors(@Param("floors") Set<Floor> floors);
```

doesn't work because i am not able to see this relation table only House and Floor.
Can you help me please with an idea how to solve this ?

Thanks!

I tried to use mapped by and I wanted to get rid of this intermediate table. But I think the best way is to use this relation

Comment: JPQL doesn't give you direct access to relation tables, just entity tables. What does your entity look like, and have you tried deleting the entity instances instead of using JPQL delete queries? By deleting the entity and managing the relationships on it, JPA will clean up the relation tables for you. Otherwise, you can modify the table to cascade delete the relational table entries when the floor is deleted.